# Calculating default buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

According to the [Android SDK Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools) you no longer need to define the buildToolsVersion property in the project's build.gradle, as a default version is used

> If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your
>   project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that
>   the plugin specifies.

However, I am trying to configure our continuous integration server to sign the compiled application and I can't figure out which version of build tools to use.

If the build.gradle defines a buildToolsVersion then this can be extracted, but how would I find the "default" version pragmatically if none is defined?

All the documentation says to use the ["default"](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools) or ["recommended"](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/) version, but never defines how to find this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One does not calculate nor define the default/recommended value for `buildToolsVersion`, hence it defaults to the latest build-tools, always matching the target API level, which is being defined by the [targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms). the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools) of the SDK Build Tools read:

> SDK Build Tools release notes
> Android SDK Build-Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for building Android apps. It's installed in the /build-tools/ directory.

> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies.

And most interestingly:

> To use a different version of the build tools, specify it using buildToolsVersion in your module's build.gradle, as follows ...

This means, that one can simply remove the `buildToolsVersion` property from a module's `build.gradle`. before one always had to change two values when updating the target API - and even more often when updating the build-tools . There are also new [requirements](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) for the Play Store.

Comment: This seems to be correct, although I think the Android docs could be a little clearer.

Comment: This can be tested by uninstalling all of the SDK Build-Tools and running an assembleRelease. This will install the latest SDK Buil-Tool version that matches the targetSdkVersion as you describe

Comment: Meanwhile (as of AGP 7.1) it's just `minSdk`, `compileSdk`, `targetSdk` ...

Comment: This is not correct. I added another answer.

Comment: @MrK not leates but default .. what means Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 and latest is 34.0.0

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify the `buildToolsVersion`, the Android Gradle Plugin will use its default build tools. For each AGP [release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin), the default build tools version is documented.

At the moment of writing, the latest AGP version is 7.3.0, and it will use build tools 30.0.3 by default. (The latest build tools is 33.0.1.)

This is also clarified in the [build tools release notes page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools):

> If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your
> project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that
> the plugin specifies.